# How to extend neural networks api to support convolutional n.n

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, encog

I'm using [Encog](https://github.com/encog/encog-java-core) Machine learning api and it uses a Flat implementation to optimize performance, where it assumes that there is a full connection between two layers.

I want to extend it to support convolutional neural networks, But I've no idea how to update the api to support it.

I've thought about setting the weights of the input that doesn't get into the result of the convolution with zero, but am not sure how this will affect the backpropagation algorithm

Answer (score 2):

That is a non-trivial enhancement; however, it is a planned addition to Encog.

Comment: Would be very pleased to see this happen

Comment: two years on - has this "planned addition" been dropped?

Comment: Not at this point.  I just do not do a great deal of computer vision ML at this point, so I really do not need CNN's myself.  If someone extends Encog to add CNN's I would be glad to help incorporate it.